# Difference between -XX:-UseParallelGC and -XX:+UseParallelGC

Tags: java, jvm-arguments

What is the difference between -XX:+UseParallelGC and -XX:-UseParallelGC? Most links indicate the first, but http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html mentions the second.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the documentation:

> Boolean options are turned on with `-XX:+<option>` and turned off with `-XX:-<option>`

So it means that `-XX:+UseParallelGC` will turn on the parallel garbage collection, and `-XX:-UseParallelGC` will turn it off.

Answer (score 4):

The line:

```
-XX:+UseParallelGC
```

Enables the **ParallelGC**. Note the `+` sign

The line:

```
-XX:-UseParallelGC
```

Disables it. Note the `-` sign.